# Why can't I stop these objects from falling down?

Tags: physics, cell-fracture

I have two sets of objects that I want to fall apart at different times. I used the "cell fracture" addon to divide them up. The FIGHT set works great. I set all the parts to "deactivation" and they will stand, as they should, until I knock them down with a moving object.

Now I want the ING to do the same. I want it to still be standing after the FIGHT set of objects have fallen. All the parts of ING are set to deactivation. However, as soon as FIGHT falls, it activates the ING to fall also.

No problem, I thought. Just change the "velocity linear" and "angular" settings of all the parts in ING to something high. Now the moving parts of FIGHT won't be enough to set them off. Nope. Makes no difference what I change those settings to, the ING series will fall every time.

I thought maybe it was all the parts of ING being set as convex hull. So I changed them all to MESH. But alas, the object just explodes instantly, every time. The blown apart objects then freeze halfway across the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The rigid body simulation of Blender is great - for easy objects (which means non-concave). But there are some traps you can fall in.
One is overlapping geometry (this is often the case if two objects overlap or have too high collision margin) so that it looks like the objects "explode". Sometimes you can solve this by selecting all objects, change to "individual origins" and scale them all down a bit. Sometimes you have to play detective and find the overlapping objects.

In your special case you obviously have this "exploding" problem, but anyway if you move another object to "start" the animation with the "deactivated" mechanism, the second part of the text will fall anyway because all objects move and by the chain reaction they will move the later ones as well (except you move them more far away or fake it e.g. with a invisible passive plane). So one way to solve this would be to move the second part to another collection

[image]

so they won't interact with the first part of the text (fight). But of course then afterwards the simulation might look "weird" because the objects fall "in the same place", like this:

[image]

animation:

[image]

But lucky us - i just found out for myself - you can keyframe the collection ;)

[image]

so after the frame when all move anyway like this:

[image]

just add the first collection to all theses rigid bodies and keyframe again:

[image]

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

Note: i also needed some time to get this. You have to check always what Blender is doing. E.g. if you keyframe the selected collections for rigid body, it does keyframe it for multiple objects. But just holding alt to select them, does not select it for all objects. For this you have to right click on collections -> copy to all objects.